# Assigning numbers to entries in a file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Improved Formatting

So,none of the previous approaches i used helped me to cluster my log file data :(

Now Im going to try an indexing approach..for which I need to index each log file entry based on the keyword that appears in the URL field..

example:

```
192.162.1.4 [3/May/2009 00:34:45] "GET /books/casual/4534.pdf" 200 454353  "http://ljdhjg.com" "Mozillablahblah"<br/>
190.100.1.4 [3/May/2009 00:37:45] "GET /resources/help.pdf" 200 4353 "http://ljdhjg.com" "Mozillablahblah"<br/>
192.162.1.4 [3/May/2009 00:40:45] "GET /books/serious/44.pdf" 200 234353 "http://ljdhjg.com" "Mozillablahblah"<br/>
```

....And i have thousands more entries like this..

Now all of `"books"` needs to be assigned a number...1 (say)..and next, `"resources"` needs to be assigned 2..how do i go about accomplishing this in C# ? I mean,i know the logic...

Extract keyword..assign number..compare keyword array with each line of file..if match,assign. But since im new to C#, i dont really know how to code the above mentioned logic. So..help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this adhoc approach to assign (I am assuming this means prefixing the index to the log entry),

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the indexed entry.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entry">The log entry.</param>
/// <returns>The log entry prefixed with the index.</returns>
private string GetIndexedEntry(string entry)
{
    string keyword = GetKeyword(entry);

    switch (keyword)
    {
        case "books":
            entry = "1 : " + entry;
            break;

        case "resources":
            entry = "2 : " + entry;
            break;
    }

    // Alternative code (using dictionary)
    // entry = keywordIndexDictionary[keyword] + " : " + entry;

    return entry;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the keyword.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entry">The log entry.</param>
/// <returns>The keyword for the specified log entry.</returns>
private string GetKeyword(string entry)
{
    int index = entry.IndexOf("\"GET");
    entry = entry.Substring(index + ("\"GET").Length);
    index = entry.IndexOf('"');
    entry = entry.Substring(0, index).Trim();
    return entry.Split('/')[1];
}

// Alternative approach
/// <summary>
/// Stores the keyword-index pair
/// </summary>
private Dictionary<string, int> keywordIndexDictionary;

/// <summary>
/// Builds the dictionary.
/// </summary>
private void BuildDictionary()
{
    // Build the dictionary manually 
    // or alternatively read from an settings file and then build the dictionary
    keywordIndexDictionary.Add("books", 1);
    keywordIndexDictionary.Add("resources", 2);
}
```

The call to `GetIndexedEntry()` would look like,

```
string indexedLogEntry = GetIndexedEntry(logEntry);
```

where `logEntry` is the string representing each entry in the log file.

For a `logEntry` of

`192.162.1.4 [3/May/2009 00:34:45] "GET /books/casual/4534.pdf" 200 454353 "http://ljdhjg.com" "Mozillablahblah"`

the `indexedLogEntry` would be

`1 : 192.162.1.4 [3/May/2009 00:34:45] "GET /books/casual/4534.pdf" 200 454353 "http://ljdhjg.com" "Mozillablahblah"`

A more elegant approach is possible if one uses regular expressions.

Comment: Do I HAVE to use the switch case operation?? I mean, I have around say..40 keywords...it would be impractical for me to provide a case for each of them,wouldnt it?

Comment: You can use a `HashTable` or `Dictionary` to store the `keyword`:`index` pair. And then use it to build the index.